# Dynamic programming from cormen's book

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

When reading about dynamic programming in "Introduction to algorithms" By cormen, Chapter 15: Dynamic Programming , I came across this statement

> When developing a dynamic-programming algorithm, we follow a sequence of
> four steps:
>
> 1. Characterize the structure of an optimal solution.
> 2. Recursively define the value of an optimal solution.
> 3. Compute the value of an optimal solution, typically in a bottom-up fashion.
> 4. Construct an optimal solution from computed information.
>
> Steps 1–3 form the basis of a dynamic-programming solution to a problem. If we
> need only the value of an optimal solution, and not the solution itself, then we
> can omit step 4. When we do perform step 4, we sometimes maintain additional
> information during step 3 so that we can easily construct an optimal solution.

I did not understand the difference in step 3 and 4.

**computing the value of optimal solution**

and

**constructing the optimal solution.**

I was expecting to understand this by reading even further, but failed to understand.
Can some one help me understanding this by giving an example ?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we are using dynamic programming to work out whether there is a subset of [1,3,4,6,10] that sums to 9.

The answer to step 3 is the value, in this case "TRUE".

The answer to step 4 is working out the actual subset that sums to 9, in this case "3+6".

Answer (score 0):

In dynamical programming we most of the time end up with a huge results hash. However initially it only contains the result obtained from the first, smallest, simplest (bottom) case and by using these initial results and calculating on top of them we eventually merge to the target. At this point the last item in the hash most of the time is the target (step 3 completed). Then we will have to process it to get the desired result.

A perfect example could be finding the minimum number of cubes summing up to a target. Target is 500 and we should get [5,5,5,5] or if the target is 432 we must get [6,6].

So we can implement this task in JS as follows;

```js
function getMinimumCubes(tgt){
  var maxi = Math.floor(Math.fround(Math.pow(tgt,1/3))),
      hash = {0:[[]]},
      cube = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= maxi; i++){
    cube = i*i*i;
    for (var j = 0; j <= tgt - cube; j++){
      hash[j+cube] = hash[j+cube] ? hash[j+cube].concat(hash[j].map(e => e.concat(i)))
                                  : hash[j].map(e => e.concat(i));
    }
  }
  return hash[tgt].reduce((p,c) => p.length < c.length ? p:c);
}

var target = 432,
    result = [];
console.time("perf:");
result = getMinimumCubes(target);
console.timeEnd("perf:");
console.log(result);
```

So in this code, `hash = {0:[[]]},` is step 1; the nested for loops which eventually prepare the `hash[tgt]` are in fact step 3 and the `.reduce()` functor at the return stage is step 4 since it shapes up the last item of the hash (`hash[tgt]`) to give us the desired result by filtering out the shortest result among all results that sum up to the target value.

To me the step 2 is somewhat meaningless. Not because of the mention of recursion but also by meaning. Besides I have never used nor seen a recursive approach in dynamical programming. It's best implemented with `while` or `for` loops.